# Convert JSON to Object with JAXB only if all fields are filled out

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, jersey

I'm building a RESTful web service with Jersey. I use JAXB to convert incoming JSON objects into Java objects. Unfortunately this approach allows to create Java objects which don't have all mandatory fields. If I have 3 mandatory fields but the JSON contains only 1 field, I would like to see an exception thrown.

Resource class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Resource {
  private int    field1;
  private String field2;
  private String field3;

  public Resource() {

  }

  ...
}
```

REST class:

```
@Path("resource")
public class ResourceREST {

  ...

  @POST
  @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String createResource(Resource resource) {
      ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Is there any possibility to do this with JAXB? If not, how can I realize this input validation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use bean validation to annotate the fields of the bean and validate them. It is not -and should not- be a part of parsing but a separate validation step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the same scenario and applied some logic to fix this after the `JSON` is generated.

In a List add those `Field Names` that you considered as mandatory.

```
public static final List<String> REQUIRED_FIELDS = new ArrayList<String>();
    static {
        REQUIRED_FIELDS.add("Field1");
        REQUIRED_FIELDS.add("Field2");
    };
```

Send those `JSON` that you have build to a validate method.

Your validate method should be like this.

```
public void validateRequiredFields(JSONObject jsonObject, List<String> requiredFields) throws ParserException, Exception {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Entering validateForRequiredFields");
        }
        List<String> missingFields = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            if (requiredFields != null) {
                for (String requiredField : requiredFields) {
                    if (ifObjectExists(jsonObject, requiredField)) {
                        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jsonObject.getString(requiredField))) {
                            missingFields.add(requiredField);
                        }
                    } else {
                        missingFields.add(requiredField);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (missingFields != null && missingFields.size() > 0) {
                throw new Exception(missingFields);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new ParserException("Error occured in validateRequiredFields", e);
        }
    }
```